# Meteor update in loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to do an update for each checkbox which is checked.

So I made a for-loop. But this doesn't work, as just some of the element gets an update. I think the for-loop is faster than the update.

Can I send an array with all _id's to the update() to work on that?

```
var inputFields = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    newId = 123;

for(var i = 0; i < inputFields.length; i++) {
    if (inputFields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputFields[i].checked == true) {
        Articles.update({_id: inputFields[i].getAttribute('data-id')}, {$set: { parent: newId }});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array in the update query using `$in` and `multi` operators. Read more about `$in` operator [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in).

```
 Articles.update({_id: {$in : inputFieldsArray} }, {$set: { parent: newId }}, { multi : true} );
```

Comment: Note that `multi: true` only works on the server. If you want to update on the client you have to do each document one at a time and select it by `_id`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'll do a method call to do the update on the server.